# Continuously differentiable curves

Tags: measure-theory

How one can show that the unit cube $[0,1]^d$ cannot be covered by countably many continuously differentiable curves?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [Sard's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem), if $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^d$ is continuously differentiable and $d>1$, then $f(\mathbb R)$ has measure zero. So, a countable union of continuously differentiable curves would have measure zero in $\mathbb R^d$, while the unit cube has measure $1$.